# Why the Download Pages of our products are not indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index, ranking

I have a question about pages indexed, hope you can help me out, thank you in advance.

Recently, we found our French site's two download pages are not indexed by Google. The URL of the French site is: `www.imobie.fr`, the two non-indexed pages are:

- https://www.imobie.fr/anytrans/download.htm and
- https://www.imobie.fr/phonerescue/download.htm

Our website is not a new site, and the two pages always rank well in Google for several years, because the organic keywords are brand related, like AnyTrans Download or PhoneRescue Download, or just search AnyTrans or Download. Recently, we found the two pages' organic traffic declined sharply and then found they had disappeared from Google SERP, and they are not indexed by Google.

Then we checked Google Webmaster tool, in the Coverage > Crawled – currently not indexed found the two pages, then submitted them to Google for index yesterday, and found they are still not indexed by Google today. And the Google Analytics shows the organic traffic started to decline sharply from Aug.27th.

About this problem, we had tried the following methods,

1. Checked the two pages have “no index” tag in the page source – No
2. Checked robots file and see if we blocked the two pages from crawling - No
3. Checked the two pages' `re=canonical` tag and see if they are linked to the wrong pages – No
4. Checked if the pages for mobile phones has “no index” tag (Because our products are desktop software, for mobile users, we designed some pages to convert mobile users, only work for mobile users. Normally, we add “no index” to block them from Google crawling)  - Yes, they have.
5. Checked “Remove URLs” to see if we removed the two pages from google SERP by mistake – No.
6. Submit the two pages to Google via URL Inspection, but they are still not indexed.

So far, the pages are still not indexed by Google. And I just searched `site:imobie.fr/anytrans/ download` in Bing and yahoo.co.jp, I found I can find https://www.imobie.fr/anytrans/download.htm in bing, but can’t in Yahoo. Therefore, I want to know why our pages are disappeared from Search engines’ SERPs, and not indexed, and how to make them indexed again. If possible, also hope you can check if the two pages have any not-friendly codes in the page source.